# Mapbox updating properties goes in geometry

Tags: mapbox, geojson

When I add a new Marker on the map I add a property to be able to use a custom icon. Then I save the geoJson and, but when I see the saved geojson I see the prperty set in wrong place.

This is the code:

```
function updtateMarker(t, layer) {

   // t is the value I need to save in property "iconSet"
   // layer is the layer ID

    var marker = featureGroup._layers[layer];
    console.log("### updtate Marker ###");

    // if marker already exists it works good
    if (marker.feature && marker.feature.properties && marker.feature.properties.iconSet) {

        marker.feature.properties.iconSet = t;
        marker.setIcon(arrayIcon[t]); //  update icon on Map

    } else {

        // Marker is new, it doesn't exist

        //  update marker icon on Map
        marker.setIcon(runnaloIcon[t]);

       marker.feature = {properties: {iconSet: t}};
       // *****   THIS IS WRONG: why? ******
       // this will be saved in "geometry" !??!

    }

}
```

This is th **wrong** geojson:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "properties": {
            "iconSet": 2
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [9.672668, 44.934964]
        }
    }
```

This is what I need:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "iconSet": 2
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [9.672668, 44.934964]
    }
}
```

Just to complete my code this is the saving part

```
 var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();
 var convertedData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding the property when I created the new Marker instead of when using it forst time.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (event) {

   // Each time a featuree is created, it's added to the over arching feature group

   if (event.layerType == "marker") {

       var layer = event.layer;

       // set the  first property
       feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};
       feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
       var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
       props.iconSet = 1;  // default value

   }

})
```